# Improve efficiency in R (vectorization?)

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, vectorization, memory-efficient

I have script in R that takes 8 minutes to run which basically compares date ranges for 800 records over a multi-year period.  This is way too long.  I am new to R and pretty sure it has to do with my embedded loops.  Also, when I tried converting my data to toy problem it doesn't seem to work.  I had been dealing with array types which I read in from excel.

```
# data vectors
ID <- c("1e", "1f", "1g")
StartDate <- c(1, 2, 4)
EndDate <- c(3, 4, 5)
Type <- c("A", "B", "B")
Qty <- c(.5, 2.5, 1)

# table rows and headers
Days <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
setOfTypes <- c("A", "B")

# get subset of active IDs for each day in table
ActiveID <- data.frame()
for(d in 1:length(Days)){
  check <- StartDate<=Days[d] & EndDate>=Days[d]
  subsetID <- subset(ID, check)
  strSubsetID <- c()
  for(i in 1:length(subsetID)){
    strSubsetID <- paste(ID, subsetID[i], sep=",")
}
ActiveID[d,1] <- strSubsetID
}

# calculate quantity counts by day and type
Count <- matrix(,length(Days),length(setOfTypes))
for(d in 1:length(Days)){
  for(t in 1:length(setOfTypes))
    check <- Type == setOfTypes[t] & sapply(ID, grepl, x=ActiveID[d,1])
    tempCount <- subset(Types, check)
    Count[t,d] <- sum(tempCount)
  }
}
```

The result should be a table (days x types) with each element consisting of the sum of Qty for active IDs on given day and type.

I am looking to vectorize this code so it runs faster when I apply to much larger data set!!  Please help, thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the reshape2 or plyr packages?

Comment: Please show your expected result as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't run as is, so I have no way of knowing exactly what you are looking for. Your description suggests that you want the sum of `Qty` for each of `Days` between `StartDate` and `EndDate`, grouped by `Type`. This will produce such a matrix:

```
df <- data.frame(ID,StartDate,EndDate,Type,Qty,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
Days <- min(StartDate):max(EndDate)

is.between <- function(x,df) with(df,x>=StartDate & x<=EndDate)
get.sums   <- function(df) sapply(Days,function(d,df) sum(df[is.between(d,df),"Qty"]),df)
do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df,df$Type), get.sums))
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# A  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.0    0
# B  0.0  2.5  2.5  3.5    1
```

Here's a data.table approach that might be faster. Note the different definitions of `is.between(...)` and `get.sums(...)`.

```
DT <- data.table(df,key="Type")
is.between <- function(x,a,b) x>=a & x <= b
get.sums   <- function(day) DT[,list(day,Qty=sum(Qty[is.between(day,StartDate,EndDate)])),by=Type]
long       <- rbindlist(lapply(Days,get.sums))
result     <- dcast.data.table(long,Type~day,value.var="Qty")
result
#    Type   1   2   3   4 5
# 1:    A 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.0 0
# 2:    B 0.0 2.5 2.5 3.5 1
```

---

Here are some benchmarks with a hopefully more representative example dataset (800 rows, 500 start dates, total date range >900 days), and also testing @Arun's answer.

```
# more representative example
set.seed(1)  # for reproducibility
StartDate <- sample(1:500,800,replace=TRUE)
EndDate   <- StartDate + rpois(800,400)
Type      <- sample(LETTERS[1:20],800,replace=TRUE)
Qty       <- rnorm(800,10,2)
Days      <- min(StartDate):max(EndDate)
df        <- data.frame(StartDate,EndDate,Type,Qty, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comparison of the data frame approach, and the two data table approaches.

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
DT <- data.table(df,key="Type")
f.df <- function() {
  is.between <- function(x,df) with(df,x>=StartDate & x<=EndDate)
  get.sums   <- function(df) sapply(Days,function(d,df) sum(df[is.between(d,df),"Qty"]),df)
  do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df,df$Type), get.sums))
}
f.dt1 <- function() {
  is.between <- function(x,a,b) x>=a & x <= b
  get.sums   <- function(day) DT[,list(day,Qty=sum(Qty[is.between(day,StartDate,EndDate)])),by=Type]
  long       <- rbindlist(lapply(Days,get.sums))
  dcast.data.table(long,Type~day,value.var="Qty")
}
f.dt2 <- function() {
  lookup <- data.table(StartDate=Days, EndDate=Days)
  setkey(lookup)
  j_olaps <- foverlaps(DT, lookup, by.x=c("StartDate", "EndDate"), type="any")
  dcast.data.table(j_olaps, Type ~ StartDate, value.var="Qty", fun.agg=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
}
identical(f.dt1(),f.dt2())   # same result? YES!
# [1] TRUE
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f.df(),f.dt1(),f.dt2(),times=10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr        min         lq    median        uq       max neval
#   f.df() 1199.76370 1212.03787 1222.6558 1243.8743 1275.5526    10
#  f.dt1() 1634.92675 1664.98885 1689.7812 1714.2662 1798.9121    10
#  f.dt2()   91.53245   95.19545  129.2789  158.0789  208.1818    10
```

So @Arun's approach is ~10X faster than the df approach , and ~17X faster than the dt approach above.

Comment: THIS IS AWESOME!! Thanks so much. I see improvement from 8 min down to 25 seconds. Is this the most efficient?  I will have to apply this on even larger data sets so I would love to see this get down to 5-10 seconds on 800 records and 1000 day time record.

Comment: Thanks much.  I will try this out, I trust it works better.  The reason I am choosing R is that I am using it inside Alteryx software.  If you haven't checked out Alteryx for big data and advanced analytics I highly recommend it.

Comment: +1. Based on your answer, I think this solution could make use of the newly implemented overlap joins in 1.9.4. I've provided an answer. It'd be great if you could also double-check it (to make sure I've understood it right).

Comment: You should accept @Arun's answer, as his is by far the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at @jihoward's code, this seems like a case for *overlap joins*, which was very recently implemented in v1.9.4 of `data.table`. The function is called `foverlaps()`. Here's how we can use it:

First we create a lookup table with the date ranges for which we'd like the overlapping join for. This is constructed using the variable `Days` from @jihoward's code. The start and end dates are identical in your case.

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.4
lookup <- data.table(StartDate=Days, EndDate=Days)
setkey(lookup)
```

Then we compute the overlap join using `foverlaps()`. The overlap type here is specified as `any`. Have a look at `?foverlaps` to figure out what that means, and the other types of overlaps one can do.

```
j_olaps = foverlaps(DT, lookup, by.x=c("StartDate", "EndDate"), type="any")
```

Now that we've the overlaps, we can simply cast it as follows:

```
dcast.data.table(j_olaps, Type ~ StartDate, value.var="Qty", fun.agg=sum, na.rm=TRUE)

#    Type   1   2   3   4 5
# 1:    A 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.0 0
# 2:    B 0.0 2.5 2.5 3.5 1
```

I believe this should be much faster than having to do a vector scan based subset on each element in `Days`. It'd be great to know how much speedup you get, if at all!

HTH

Comment: Ran some benchmarks above - yours is by far the fastest way.